# python: re.search doesn't start at beginning of string?

Tags: python, regex

I'm working on a Flask API, which takes the following regex as an endpoint:

```
([0-9]*)((OK)|(BACK)|(X))*
```

That means I'm expecting a series of numbers, and the OK, BACK, X keywords multiple times in succession after the numbers.

I want to split this regex and do different stuff depending which capture groups were present.

My approach was the following:

```
endp = endp.encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
    match = re.search(r"([0-9]*)", str(endp), re.I)
    if match:
        n = match.groups()
        logging.info('nums: ' + str(n[0]))

    match = re.search(r"((OK)|(BACK)|(X))*", str(endp), re.I)
    if match:
        s1 = match.groups()
        for i in s1:
            logging.info('str: ' + str(i[0]))
```

Using the /12OK endpoint, getting the numbers works just fine, but for some reason capturing the rest of the keywords are unsuccessful. I tried reducing the second capture group to only

```
match = re.search(r"(OK)*", str(endp), re.I)
```

I constantly find the following in s1 (using the reduced regex):

```
(None,)
```

originally (with the rest of the keywords):

```
(None, None, None, None)
```

Which I suppose means the regex pattern does not match anything in my endp string (why does it have 4 Nones? 1 for each keyword, but what the 4th is there for?). I validated my endpoint (the regex against the same string too) with a regex validator, it seems fine to me. I understand that `re.match` is supposed to get matches from the beginning, therefore I used the `re.search` method, as the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#search-vs-match) points out it's supposed to match anywhere in the string.

What am I missing here? Please advise, I'm a beginner in the python world.

Comment: Could you include  a sample of the data you're trying to match against ?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean `([0-9]*)((OK|BACK|X)*)` but I too would like to see examples of the things you are hoping to capture which are not currently working.

Comment: Something like `OKOKOKXXXXBACKBACK` or `0123` would match your current regex.  If the intent is to capture the repeated keywords as individual capture groups, you need as many capture groups as there are keywords to capture, or more realistically capture everything and break it up into individual keywords out of the captured group. If there can be a maximum of one each and the order is fixed, you simply want `(OK)?(BACK)?(X)?`

Comment: I'm not entirely sure if you are asking what input I want to validate against my regex, if so, I'm trying to use 12OK. Order should not be fixed. As @tripleee mentioned, I would like to capture each occurence as a separate

Comment: Examples of actual posts would be helpful in every instance -- "this is not doing what I want" fails to express what you *do* want, and the regex you posted implies that there could be a random number of repetitions like OKOKOK.  If you don't need that, the answer can be much simpler than for the most general case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it is a bit surprising that searching with `*` returns `None:

```
>>> re.search("(OK|BACK|X)*", u'/12OK').groups()
(None,)
```

But it's "correct", since `*` matches zero or more, and any pattern matches zero times in any string, that's why you see `None`. Searching with `+` somewhat solves it:

```
>>> re.search("(OK|BACK|X)+", u'/12OK').groups()
('OK',)
```

But now, searching with this pattern in `/12OKOK` still only finds one match because `+` means one or more, and it matched one time at the first `OK`. To find all occurrences you need to use `re.findall`:

```
>>> re.findall("(OK|BACK|X)", u'/12OKOK')
['OK', 'OK']
```

With those findings, your code would look as follows: (note that you don't need to write `i[0]` since `i` is already a string, unless you want to log only the first char of the string):

```
import re

endp = endp.encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
match = re.search(r"([0-9]+)", str(endp))
if match:
    n = match.groups()
    logging.info('nums: ' + str(n))

match = re.findall(r"(OK|BACK|X)", str(endp), re.I)
for i in match:
    logging.info('str: ' + str(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to match at least ONE of the groups, use `+` instead of `*`.

```
>>> endp = '/12OK'
>>> match = re.search(r"((OK)|(BACK)|(X))+", str(endp), re.I)
>>> if match:
...     s1 = match.groups()
...     for i in s1:
...         print s1
...
('OK', 'OK', None, None)
>>> endp = '/12X'
>>> match = re.search(r"((OK)|(BACK)|(X))+", str(endp), re.I)
>>> match.groups()
('X', None, None, 'X')
```

Notice that you have 4 matching groups in your expression, one for each pair of parentheses. The first match is the outer parenthesis and the second one is the first of the nested groups. In the second example, you still get the first match for the outer parenthesis and then the last one is the third of the nested ones.

Answer (score 0):

"((OK)|(BACK)|(X))*" will search for OK or BACK or X, 0 or more times. Note that the * means 0 or more, not more than 0. The above expression should have a + at the end not * as + means 1 or more.

Comment: That's hardly sufficient to resolve the OP's problem, though it's not clear to me what *exactly* they are looking for.  `(OK|BACK|X)+` would be the simple and idiomatic way to do what you are proposing.

Comment: I'm not necessarily expecting these keywords, I want to leave the option to access an endpoint with only numbers

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having two different issues, and their intersection is causing more confusion than either of them would cause on their own.

The first issue is that you're using repeated groups. Python's `re` library is not able to capture multiple matches when a group is repeated. Matching with a pattern like `(X)+` against `'XXXX'` will only capture a single `'X'` in the first group even though the whole string will be matched. The [`regex` library](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) (which is not part of the standard library) can do multiple captures, though I'm not sure of the exact commands required.

The second issue is using the `*` repetition operator in your pattern. The pattern you show at the top of the question will match on an empty string. Obviously, none of the gropus will capture anything in that situation (which may be why you're seeing a lot of `None` entries in your results). You probably need to modify your pattern so that it requires some minimal amount of valid text to count as a match. Using `+` instead of `*` might be one solution, but it's not clear to me exactly what you want to match against so I can't suggest a specific pattern.